# Algebra question on gre: $21+x^2 +(x+1)+16+22+17+x = 100$%

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

$21+x^2 +(x+1)+16+22+17+x = 100$%

The solution guide gives me $x^2 + 2x + 76 = 100$

Then $x^2+2x-24=0$

I just don't get where $x+1$ went..

I keep getting $x^2+2x+77=100$ what am I doing wrong somebody help me[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZG85.png)

[image: ddd]

Comment: This is on the GRE general test? I'm impressed. I don't recall there being quadratic equations when I took the test in $2008$. They're raising the bar!

Comment: $21 + 16+ 22 + 17 = 76$ and the $1$ from $(x+1)$ gives $77$. I'm with you. Either the solution's wrong or there's something you aren't telling us that changes things

Comment: Something is not right in the exercise. We are combining three odd numbers and the solution manual has a constant of 24. Double check or provide us with a picture of the page. Normally inserting page pictures to solve a problem is not so well appreciated, but if a mistake in a textbook is perceived, we would like to take a look at it...

Comment: I've added the image of problem pls help me asap

Comment: this is a practice problem for gre

Comment: After having read the question a ton of times, I believe they made a mistake. The question is flawed and since you actually did the right thing, I wouldn't sweat over it and continue to practice other problems of this useless test...Good luck!

Comment: Your arithmetic is right. With the information you are given, you should end up with $x^2+2x-23=0$, which is not factorable, but you could still use the quadratic formula to solve. However, it is clear the publishers intended their problem to use factoring (since that is the way they published the solution), so the conclusion is that there is an error in the statement of the problem.

Comment: One more severe typo in a textbook !

Comment: yeah ive been studying for over 3 hours I thuoght I am missing something thx all

Comment: I can tell you are using Manhattan GRE's books (because I work as a private tutor, teaching the GRE among other subjects). Those books are full of bad (unrealistic, unrepresentative) problems and typos. You should practice with the official practice books instead.

Comment: OP is correct, the solution manual is wrong.